# How do you share to safari in iOS?

Tags: ios, safari

System: iOS 16.5.1, iPhone 14 pro max.

I noticed I can share to other browsers (chrome, Firefox) from the share menu but there is not an option for safari.

For example I might tap a link in google maps which opens in a modal embedded browser. The only way I’ve figured out how to get that page into a regular safari tab is to:

1. Tap share icon
2. `copy` the url to clipboard
3. Switch app to safari
4. Tap tabs icon
5. Tap `+`
6. Tap the address bar to focus it
7. Double tap the address bar to get the textbox context menu
8. If I’m lucky, `paste and go` is an option, otherwise I have to paste then tap `go` as a separate step.

So that’s 8 or 9 interactions compared to the 2 needed to open something in chrome or Firefox. Is there a way to get safari into the share list? Or is there a more efficient way for me to open stuff from other apps in safari?

Comment: When I open a webpage in Google maps (or most apps that don't switch to Safari automatically) on iOS 16 I get a Safari button in the bottom right. What does it look like for you?

Answer (score 2):

Most apps provide an Open Link option, however for one that specifically opens in Safari and is available even when apps don't provide it you have two options.

Option 1: Create a shortcut. In the Shortcuts app, create a shortcut. In the shortcut details, select "Show in Share Sheet" then set it to receive "URLs" and add a single action "Open URLs" to open the "Shortcut Input."

Option 2 ($2): *Opener* from the App Store. [website](https://www.opener.link). This App provides "Open In..." functionality to many targets, not just Safari.